# Is it possible to retrieve a Facebook Messenger thread between two friends using a Facebook API

Tags: ios, facebook, reactjs, messenger

I am developing a React Native App and have integrated the Facebook SDK for React Native.

I have been browsing Facebook For Developers in an effort to learn how I could retrieve the Facebook Messenger Thread between the logged-in user and a friend. The Graph API doesn't seem to allow for this. The "User Threads" and "User Conversations" edges look to be deprecated...

Is there a way to do this?

Best, 
Patrick

Comment: No there is no way to do that

Comment: I came to that conclusion but just wanted to be sure. Thanks a lot!